# How to programmatically open and modify ODT file from Calc Macro

Tags: libreoffice, odt, libreoffice-basic

I am writing a Macro programm in a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet. This macro should do the following (amongst other things):

- open an existing ODT text document as a template
- search and replace some strings with new values
- save a copy of this as a new file
- generate and open a PDF version

Is this possible somehow using LibreOffice Basic only? I have found nothing in the Libreoffice docs and examples and only this slightly related answer here on SO: [How to programatically modify Open/Libre Office odt document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039575/how-to-programatically-modify-open-libre-office-odt-document)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> open an existing ODT text document as a template

The method to open a document is [loadComponentFromURL](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1frame_1_1XComponentLoader.html), for example https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/stardesktop.html. There is nothing especially difficult about opening a document in Writer from a Calc macro, as LibreOffice components are well integrated. Remember to use the object returned from opening the document instead of `ThisComponent`.

> search and replace some strings with new values

[Andrew's Macro Document](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) section *7.14. Search And Replace* shows some ways to do this.

> save a copy of this as a new file

The command is `storeAsURL` which is like "save as", not to be confused with `storeToURL` which would modify the existing file. See https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Saving_a_document.

> generate and open a PDF version

Generating a PDF is like any other save. The only difference is that the export filter `writer_pdf_Export` must be specified. An example is at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/178818/how-i-export-pdf-using-macro/.

As for opening the PDF, what application do you want to open it? LibreOffice Draw can open a PDF although it's not a normal PDF viewer. [Shell](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/he/text/sbasic/shared/03130500.html) can call the viewer of your choice.

Comment: Perhaps a little more needs to be said about "save" and "export", the difference that TDF sees in these actions. "Saving" means the document can be opened in the same program for editing, "export" - the file will be written to disk, but for editing you will need to use another program. Creating a PDF file is exactly "export". After this clarification, the last paragraph becomes clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great help, Jim. Especially that Macro doc by Andrew is a great resource. I am making good progress and will post some code here when done.